# Firefox mobile: height 100vh is including the navigation bar height

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a container that fill all browser height. To do that, I'm using vh unit:

```
section{
  background-image: ...;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section .container{ 
  height: 100vh; 
}
```

The problem happens in mobile Firefox. The container height is bigger than viewport height. It' look like Firefox is including the navigation bar height in the calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by topbar?

Comment: @SLaks The navigation bar.

Comment: I think this is fairly unavoidable, from just playing with the app on iOS. If you can imagine the rendering stack for the app, the navbar is at a fixed position above the actual viewport the browser is rendering in.

Comment: Any solution yet?